# Multiple Databases in Django

Tags: python, django, multiple-databases

I've 2 DB in my one Django app. The two DB's are on the same network, ie on LAN. So, I suppose the HOST IP will be different. **Wouldnt it be?**

As of right now, to test my code, I've provided same HOST but different PORT.

So, my DB settings are as follow:-

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'vms_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '8000',         
    },
    'users': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'aramex_vms_db',              
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                  
        'PORT': '8080',                      
    }
}
```

When I `syncdb` it, it returns an error saying:-

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)")
```

But when I use the same port, it works fine but the tables are made in **default** DB. I know the migrate command by default works on `default` DB.

1) But what if I want that there should be different tables for default and different for users,  how will I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate your database users:

```
$ ./manage.py migrate --database=users
```

As you can see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#synchronizing-your-databases

If you want to select your database while you retrieve an entry:

```
#default dabatase
Author.objects.all()

#custom database
Author.objects.using('DATABASE_NAME').all()
```

Further information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database

Comment: I know what you have provided. I want that What if I want say `Authors` table in default and `Users` table is some other DB? How would I do that?

Comment: NO. I mean that no tables should be there in both default and other DB. There should be 1 table in default and another table in other DB.,

Comment: Please provide your valuable knowledge on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952605/django-multiple-db-multiple-models