# Django - multiple DB + multiple models

Tags: python, database, django, django-models, django-orm

I have two databases and two models:one the admin and the is user.

I want to sync my models to the two databases; admin model to database A and user model to database B;

so my problem the how to sync the two models to two databases? User should in default DB and admin in admin model.

Here's what I've tried:-

```
class User(models.Model):
    job_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    time = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True, db_index = True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'user_data'



class Admin(models.Model):
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    length = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    breadth = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    height = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    dsp_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    time = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True, db_index = True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'admin_data'
```

Here are my settings:-

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['manager.router.DatabaseAppsRouter']
DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {
                        'user_data': 'default', 
                        'admin_data':'admin_db'
                        }

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'gor_vms',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',             
            'PORT': '',                      
        },
        'admin_db': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
            'NAME': 'admin_vms_db',                     
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '',         
        }
    }
```

Upon using south, the migrations are created but when I migrate it it returns an error. saying `south.db.db = south.db.dbs[database]
KeyError: 'gor_vms'`

Also, `DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['manager.router.DatabaseAppsRouter']` throws an error saying `No named module manager.router`

How do I sync the 2 DB's with 2 different models.

PS: I've read various threads on SO, but didnt got the correct answer. Kindly help

**EDIT**

I've tried this as well.

**AdminRouter**

```
class AdminRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'admin_data':
            return 'admin_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'admin_data':
            return 'admin_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'admin_data' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'admin_data':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, model):

        if db == 'admin_db':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'admin_data'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'admin_data':
            return False
        return None
```

**GorRouter**

```
class UserRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'user_data':
            return 'default'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'user_data':
            return 'default'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'user_data' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'user_data':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, model):

        if db == 'default':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'user_data'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'user_data':
            return False
        return None
```

**SETTINGS**

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['../modules/data/admin_db_router.AdminRouter','../modules/data/user_db_router.UserRouter']

        DATABASES = {
            'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
                'NAME': 'gor_vms',
                'USER': 'root',
                'PASSWORD': '',
                'HOST': '127.0.0.1',             
                'PORT': '',                      
            },
            'admin_db': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
                'NAME': 'admin_vms_db',                     
                'USER': 'root',
                'PASSWORD': '',
                'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
                'PORT': '',         
            }
        }
```

So, to sync up the DB, I following these steps:-
1) `python manage.py schemamigration data --initial`

2) `python manage.py syncdb`

It returns a traceback saying:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 92, in handle_noargs
    syncdb.Command().execute(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 61, in handle_noargs
    seen_models = connection.introspection.installed_models(tables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 1254, in installed_models
    if router.allow_syncdb(self.connection.alias, model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 272, in allow_syncdb
    for router in self.routers:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 230, in routers
    router = import_by_path(r)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 21, in import_by_path
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 33, in import_module
    raise TypeError("relative imports require the 'package' argument")
TypeError: relative imports require the 'package' argument
```

How would I get different models in different DB's. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

In your settings, the `DATABASE_ROUTERS` list should contain *python* path (ie : `'modules.data.admin_db_router.AdminRouter', ...`), not filesystem path. Note that usual PYTHONPATH / `sys.path` requirements apply, ie in the above example the `modules` and `data` directories must be python packages and the directory *containing* `modules` must be in your `sys.path` one way or another.

As a side note, Python is not Java so you don't need a different module per class. I'd personally put both `AdminRouter` and `UserRooter` classes in a same `routers.py` module.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was a noob mistake. But I'm still facing a problem. Since I'm using South. How do I use/schema-migrate the two DB's with different models?

Comment: I perform the following steps for DB models:- 1) `./manage.py schemamigration --initial` 2) I `syncdb` both the DB's. 3) `./manage.py migrate data` (data contains my models.py file which has both the User and admin model). When I perform the 3 command it does not migrate the models. Here what it prints out.`Running migrations for data:
 - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
 > data:0001_initial
 - Loading initial data for data.
`

Comment: When I do `./manage.py schemamigration --initial`, the 0001_initial.py file contains `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from south.utils import datetime_utils as datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import SchemaMigration
from django.db import models


class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        pass

    def backwards(self, orm):
        pass

    models = {
        
    }

    complete_apps = ['data']`

Comment: Why the file is empty?